Correct way to install NVCC after installing Ubuntu 22.04
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04, and during the installation, I let it install proprietary drivers, so it seems that I have the correct NVIDIA drivers (535.183.01) and CUDA (12.2) already installed.
nvidia-smi shows :
NVIDIA-SMI 535.183.01
Driver Version: 535.183.01
CUDA Version: 12.2
...

apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-535 shows :
*** 535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1
...

But I cannot find nvcc for instance.
Does it mean CUDA 12.2 is installed... but only partially?
When following the NVIDIA CUDA Installation Guide for Linux and the  Pre-installation Actions, I see that I must Handle Conflicting Installation Methods.
But how can I know how CUDA has been installed, since it was done automatically by the Ubuntu installer?
Should I just follow the Package Manager Installation for Ubuntu blindly and see what happens?
I am afraid I will reinstall the CUDA toolkit on a previously installed but different version.

just saw this and this, CUDA might not be installed at all

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This site works a bit differently from a discussion forum. Please don't comment on your own question. Edit your question instead. You may also click on the Edit button below the question. The comments are our channel to ask you for clarification and provide you with helpful tips.

This question is similar to: How do I install NVIDIA and CUDA drivers into Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

nvidia-smi is just reporting the cuda version supported, not what's installed.  See answers 1077061 or 1219761 for installation methods.

This question is similar to: How do I find the package that provides a file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe the closest similar question is this one
